# How can I make the DataGridView select and focus on the last row I added to it?

Tags: c#

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtItemId.Text, txtItemName.Text,txtQuantity.Text, txtPrice.Text);
```

The above code adds a new row with the values I entered in textboxes, but the `DataGridView` keeps selecting the first row even if it contains more than one row. What I want is to make `DataGridView` select the last row I already added. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the add line set:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount-1].Selected = true;
```

**not tested but that should work :)

**Edit**

I already tested and in order to get the result with no bugs, set this properties like this

[image]

[image]